# how to configure ASP.net Core WebAPI on windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have made a simple ASP.Net Core WebAPI it works fine local machine using Postman. But unable to configure on main Windows 2008 Server  for accessing it from different applications.
We have taken Static IP address for our server.
Please help to configure WebAPI

Comment: Windows Server 2008! That's not even supported by Microsoft is it?

Comment: No you can't, Asp.net core project are not supported to run in windows server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Windows server 2008 is not supported to run .NET core on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70#supported-releases